# summation of all prime numbers under 2 million

Tags: javascript

this code put calculate all the prime numbers that is bellow 2 million and the calculate a summation of them, I don't think that the prime numbers are wrong but I receive sum of them as 143010484903 , but the correct answer is 142913828922.

can anyone help me what's wrong? I'm new to JS.

```js
let num = 3;
let primes = [2];

while (num < 2000000) {
  let sqrtNum = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num));
  for (i = 0; sqrtNum >= primes[i]; i++) {
    if (num % primes[i] == 0) {
      num += 2;
      i = 0;
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  primes.push(num);
  num += 2;
}

let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; primes[i] < 2000000; i++) {
  sum += primes[i];
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is adding composites to your primes list:

```js
let num = 3;
let primes = [2];

while (num < 123) {
  let sqrtNum = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num));
  for (i = 0; sqrtNum >= primes[i]; i++) {
    if (num % primes[i] == 0) {
      num += 2;
      i = 0;
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  primes.push(num);
  num += 2;
}
console.log(...primes)
```

Notice 121 (11 x 11) in the above list.

The problem is in the logic of your while loop and the way you are managing the variable `num`. Consider what happens when you are testing the composite value 115  You'll be in the portion of your loop where `n = 115`:

```
  let sqrtNum = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num));  // sqrtNum == 10
  for (i = 0; sqrtNum >= primes[i]; i++) {   // testing against [2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
    if (num % primes[i] == 0) {              // on the 3rd loop you find 115
      num += 2;                              // is divisible by 5 and increase
      i = 0;                                 // nums to 117,and find it's composite
                                             // eventually nums is 121 but you haven't changed
    } else {                                 // sqrtNum to refect you now need to search
      continue;                              // up to 11 so you think 121 is prime
    }
  }
  primes.push(num);
  num += 2;
}
```

This doesn't happen often, which is why your sum is close. Changing to `math.ceil` appears to fix this because `ceil(Math.sqrt(115))` is 11, but I'm not sure how you can prove this will always be correct.

A better idea is the sieve posted in a different answer. But here's a fix that sticks close to your code but manages `num` so you don't increase `num` without recalculating `sqrtNum`:

```js
let num = 3;
let primes =[2];

while(num <= 130) {
  let composite = false
  let sqrtNum = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num)); // sqrtNum will be calculated for each change of num
  for(i = 0; sqrtNum >= primes[i]; i++) {
    if(num % primes[i] == 0) {
      composite = true
      break
    } 
  }
  if (!composite){
    primes.push(num);
  }
  num += 2
}
// no 121!
console.log(...primes);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you do have some extra primes which are greater than `2000000` because you're flooring the value after calculating the square root. Try using .ceil() instead. You can test with even small values try taking `10` and `console.log(primes);` you can see there is extra value 11 example `[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]`;

```
let sqrtNum = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(num));
```

Comment: Hi, thank's for the answer. I try to change my code as you mention and it works, but if I try the value 10 as you said above, there is 11  in my array. I'm wondering why!

Comment: and also can you explain me more why I should use `ceil()` instead of `floor()`, I don't understand the difference :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the eror is in your code, but somewhere in your inner loop, you mess up. Your `primes.length` is also longer then in my code.

```js
let primes = [2];

mainLoop: for (let num = 3; num < 2000000; num += 2) {
  let sqrtNum = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num));
  for (let i = 0; primes[i] <= sqrtNum; i++) {
    if (num % primes[i] == 0) {
      continue mainLoop;
    }
  }
  primes.push(num);
}

let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; primes[i] < 2000000; i++) {
  sum += primes[i];
}

console.log(sum);
```

and a quick version with a sieve

```js
var sieve = Array(2000000).fill(false);
var primes = [2];

for(let i=0; i<sieve.length; i+=2) sieve[i] = true;

for(var i=3; i < sieve.length; i+=2){
  if(sieve[i]) continue;
  primes.push(i);
  for(let j=i*i; j<sieve.length; j+=i+i){
    sieve[j] = true;
  }
}

console.log(primes.reduce((a,b) => a+b));
```